# Rails Savon: No superclass method `to_xml' for #<Savon::Response

Tags: ruby, rubygems, savon

This is my first post on SO, so please let me know if I can improve my question in anyway.
I'm using the Savon version 2 gem in Rails to process a SOAP Request.  I can successfully send the request, and I see a correct response in my terminal (when setting "pretty_print_xml to true").  My code looks like this:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://example_link?WSDL", pretty_print_xml: true)

response = client.call(:method, message: {*message omitted for brevity*})

puts "Response Body: #{response.body}"
```

My issue is when I try to access the data in response via methods like "response.body" (as illustrated in the puts statement above), I get an error: ***super: no superclass method `to_xml'***
Can I have help determining the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
require 'pp'
require 'savon'

...

pp response.to_hash
```

Comment: I tried adding the two require statements, but I am still getting the same error when I call `pp response.to_hash`

Comment: You should post a workable example. Use SoapUI to create working SOAP call. Then create a simple Ruby script which creates the same XML message you've used in SoapUI.